# A more formal definition for $\max(|S_1 \setminus S_2|, |S_2 \setminus S_1|)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$, I am working with a function that returns $\max(|S_1 \setminus S_2|, |S_2 \setminus S_1|)$.

I think this definition of the function is intuitive, but I wonder if there is a correct (better) way to define it mathematically.

Comment: Do you mean $|S_1\setminus S_2|$? In other words, the number of elements in $S_1$ but not $S_2$? If so the expression seems fine to me. Are your sets infinite?

Comment: See [Primitive recursive set function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_set_function#CITEREFJensenKarp1971) and [Analogues of Primitive Recursive Functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194415/analogues-of-primitive-recursive-functions).

Comment: See also Jensen & Karp, ["Primitive recursive set functions"](https://books.google.it/books?id=TVi2AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA143).

Comment: I am working with finite sets.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try $\max(|S_1|,|S_2|)-|S_1\cap S_2|$?